# Add value to Firebase child price

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Look at my database image please. I want to add 200 to user1 price in family1,  add 300 to user2 price in family2 and add 500 to user1 price in family3

[my database image](https://www.mediafire.com/view/v7hqkbv1q58tv6f)

what im tried

```
DatabaseReference databasefamilly1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly1").child("user1").child("price");
databasefamilly1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long moneyUser1 = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        long priceAdd = 200;
        long newMoney = moneyUser1 + priceAdd;


        DatabaseReference databasefamilly1Update = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly1");
        final HashMap<String, Object> commandeData = new HashMap<>();
        commandeData.put("price", newMoney);

        databasefamilly1Update.child("user1").updateChildren(commandeData)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){


                            DatabaseReference databasefamilly2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly2").child("user2").child("price");
                            databasefamilly2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    long moneyUser1 = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                    long priceAdd = 300;
                                    long newMoney = moneyUser1 + priceAdd;


                                    DatabaseReference databasefamilly2Update = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly2");
                                    final HashMap<String, Object> commandeData = new HashMap<>();
                                    commandeData.put("price", newMoney);

                                    databasefamilly2Update.child("user2").updateChildren(commandeData)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){


                                                        DatabaseReference databasefamilly3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly3").child("user1").child("price");
                                                        databasefamilly3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                                long moneyUser1 = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                                                long priceAdd = 200;
                                                                long newMoney = moneyUser1 + priceAdd;


                                                                DatabaseReference databasefamilly3Update = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wdatabase").child("familly3");
                                                                final HashMap<String, Object> commandeData = new HashMap<>();
                                                                commandeData.put("price", newMoney);

                                                                databasefamilly3Update.child("user1").updateChildren(commandeData)
                                                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                            @Override
                                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                                                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                }else {
                                                                                    loading.dismiss();
                                                                                    String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        });



                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                            }

                                                        });
                                                    }else {
                                                        loading.dismiss();
                                                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }

                            });

                        }else {
                            loading.dismiss();
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error"+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }

});
```

My json file link https://www.mediafire.com/download/2hgbbzgujr64u0c

Comment: You've included a link to picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It would also be good to see what you've already tried.

Comment: My json file link https://www.mediafire.com/download/2hgbbzgujr64u0c

Comment: What have you tried in code so far? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo nothing concrete. help me please. I am a beginner

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i updated my question with what I tried

Comment: Explain what are you looking for. ?

Comment: @MuntasirAonik i get user1 price value, i added 200.
Then i get user2 price value, i added 300.......

Comment: @AlexMamo check my answer bro. And what happened to your facebook account?

Comment: Please don't link to an external source for code or data needed in the question. Instead just include the JSON in your question itself, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transactions` To do this . [Check Here:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

If you need to add price to 3 child you will need three transaction method. By this method you can easily add price to the child. Like if you need to add 200 , you can simply use `incrementPrice(200);`

```
void incrementPrice(final long value) {
        moneyRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                    mutableData.setValue(value);

                } else {
                    Long money = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                    assert money != null;
                    int x = money.intValue();
                    Long incrementMoney = x + value;
                    mutableData.setValue(incrementMoney);
                }
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Firebase counter increment failed!");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Firebase counter increment succeeded!");
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks..... I have to do the transactions at the same time? or after making the first transaction, I start the second in the onComplete method of the first?

Comment: Just incrementPrice(200); where you need to increment price,